# Selectively drop bars from bar plot without changing formatting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to drop one more column from the first plot without changing the width or alignment of the bars across my two plots. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
theme_min <- 
  theme(
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(), 
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
  )

# display 2 of 4 columns
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    am = factor(am, labels = c("auto", "manual")),
    vs = factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))
  ) %>% 
  filter(
    am == "auto"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = am, y = mpg, fill = vs)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,35)) + 
  theme_min +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image: 2 of 4 bars]

```
# display 1 of 4 columns
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    am = factor(am, labels = c("auto", "manual")),
    vs = factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))
  ) %>% 
  filter(
    am == "auto",
    vs == "V"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = am, y = mpg, fill = vs)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,35)) + 
  theme_min +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image: 1 of 4 bars displayed, but width is out of sync with image 1]

Comment: Suggested duplicates [always dodge a histogram](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10149571/903061), [same bar width in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24304642/903061), [don't drop zero count dodged bar plot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10326729/903061)...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to selectively drop columns by mutating the outcome variable so it equals zero for column(s) you wish to drop.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    am = factor(am, labels = c("auto", "manual")),
    vs = factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))
  ) %>% 
  filter(am == "auto") %>%
  # mutate to drop bar while maintaining bar formatting
  mutate(mpg = ifelse(vs == "S", mpg == 0, mpg)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = am, y = mpg, fill = vs)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,35)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

[image: one bar plot]